# alternative way for autocomplete in facebook app

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, encoding, autocomplete

I have solved all the parts and can load javascript variable using google app engine. Now i got stuck in autocomplete custom data. Here is my script

```
var friends=[]
{% for name in user_names %}
    vals={"id":"{{ name.id }}","name":"{{ name.user }}"}
    friends.push(vals)
{% endfor %}

$(function() {
    alert(friends); 
$( "#suggest1" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: friends,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#suggest1" ).val( ui.item.name );
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#suggest1" ).val( ui.item.name );
        $( "#suggest1-id" ).val( ui.item.id );
        return false;
    }
})
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.name + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
});
```

and html code:

```
<div class="section" id="user-section">
                    <input id='suggest1' />
                    <input type="hidden" id="suggest1-id"/>
                </div>
```

friends is the list of object containing friends and their ids. Now this autocomplete is not working. Can anybody help me to find out where am i doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried the [jquery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) widget?

Comment: Show us your code and explain what you've done to debug it. We can't possibly figure out what the problem is based on the description alone.

Comment: @Nick -what i am trying to do in in backend is to make javscript array then send it on front end.
`friend_selector=[]
            for user in self.user.friends_name:
                try:
                     ss=str(user)
                except:
                     ss=''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', user) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
                friend_selector.append(ss)
                
            friends_name='var friend-selector=['+",".join(ss)+'];'
            self.render(u'index',friends_name=[])`

Comment: @ Kevin P- yes i am using the jquery UI Autocomplete.

Comment: @bhaskaragr29 Please don't try and cram code into a comment - update your question with more details instead. And tell us what results you see, and what you've tried doing to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps it's just the format of your `friends` array is wrong?

[jQuery UI Autocomplete docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) say the items should be objects with either `label` or `value` properties, or both.

Your items have `id` and `name` properties instead.